# R | Adding index numbers

Tags: r

I have two dataset which look like below

```
Sales
Region     ReviewYear     Sales     Index
South Asia 2006            1.5      NA
South Asia 2009            4.5      NA
South Asia 2011            11       0
South Asia 2014            16.7     NA
Africa     2008            0.4      NA
Africa     2013            3.5      0
Africa     2017            9.7      NA

Strategy
Region     StrategyYear
South Asia  2011
Africa      2013
Japan       2007
SE Asia     2009
```

There are multiple regions and many review years which are not periodic and not even same for all regions. I have added a column 'Index' to dataframe 'Sales' such that for a strategy year from second dataframe, the index value is zero. I now want to change NA to a series of numbers that tell how many rows before or after that particular row is to 0 row, grouped by 'Region'.

I can do this using a for loop but that is just tedious and checking if there is a cleaner way to do this. Final output should look like

```
Sales
    Region     ReviewYear     Sales     Index
    South Asia 2006            1.5      -2
    South Asia 2009            4.5      -1
    South Asia 2011            11       0
    South Asia 2014            16.7     1
    Africa     2008            0.4      -1
    Africa     2013            3.5      0
    Africa     2017            9.7      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the two datasets by `Region` and for each `Region` create an `Index` column by subtracting the row number with the index where `StrategyYear` matches the `ReviewYear`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(Sales, Strategy, by = 'Region') %>%
  arrange(Region, StrategyYear) %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  mutate(Index = row_number() - match(first(StrategyYear), ReviewYear))

#  Region    ReviewYear Sales Index StrategyYear
#  <chr>          <int> <dbl> <int>        <int>
#1 Africa          2008   0.4    -1         2013
#2 Africa          2013   3.5     0         2013
#3 Africa          2017   9.7     1         2013
#4 SouthAsia       2006   1.5    -2         2011
#5 SouthAsia       2009   4.5    -1         2011
#6 SouthAsia       2011  11       0         2011
#7 SouthAsia       2014  16.7     1         2011
```

**data**

```
Sales <- structure(list(Region = c("SouthAsia", "SouthAsia", "SouthAsia", 
"SouthAsia", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa"), ReviewYear = c(2006L, 
2009L, 2011L, 2014L, 2008L, 2013L, 2017L), Sales = c(1.5, 4.5, 
11, 16.7, 0.4, 3.5, 9.7), Index = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

Strategy <- structure(list(Region = c("SouthAsia", "Africa", "Japan", "SEAsia"
), StrategyYear = c(2011L, 2013L, 2007L, 2009L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```